# cakephp: configuring cakephp on shared host justhost

Tags: cakephp, http-status-code-404, shared-hosting, configure

I tried to configure cakephp on justhost for my addon domain and i'm getting 404 not found error when I go to www.merryflowers.com/pages/home

Can someone please help me out?

The following are the changes I made in /webroot/index.php and /webroot/test.php

```
if (!defined('ROOT')) {
        define('ROOT', DS.'home'.DS.'xxx'.DS.'public_html'); 
}
if (!defined('APP_DIR')) {
       define('APP_DIR', 'merryflowers'); 
 }
if (!defined('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH')) {
    define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', DS.'home'.DS.'xxx');
}
```

Do I need to make some changes to the .htaccess file? and .htaccess file from which folder?

under public_html/merryflowers.com/ i have:
views, plugins and webroot folder

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems `mod_rewrite` isn't functioning properly, I can access the `webroot`directory (http://www.merryflowers.com/webroot/), which states that `core.php` can't be found. Before you look into possible `mod_rewrite` problems, ensure `core.php` is properly included.

I'm not sure you need to set all the paths in `index.php`, setting `CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH` might be enough.

You're full path isn't `DS.'home'.DS.'xxx'`, but:

`DS.'home'.DS.'xxx'.'public_html'.DS.'merryflowers.com'`

You might want to set `ROOT` and `APP_DIR` to the default values, unless you need custom paths.

Comment: Ok, I have moved the entire config folder (that contains core.php, schema folder, bootstrap.php, database.php and routes.php) to webroot. Yes, you are right, I changed back ROOT and APP_DIR to default values. Now I'm able to see www.merryflowers.com/webroot with warning 512: Cache, persistent and models folders are not writable.

Comment: Good to hear! The `config` directory shouldn't normally be in Cake's `webroot` directory and Cake would serve content from `webroot` on the root domain (merryflowers.com). But it could be this is your intended setup. The Cache directory resides in the `tmp` dir, you should CHMOD this to make it writable.

Comment: On my local server, config is not within webroot but on the shared host it is expecting config to be within webroot. I will try putting only core.php inside a new config folder within webroot and leave the original config as it was outside webroot.

Comment: which tmp dir ru talking abt? is it the one inside app? I set the permission of each folder within cache (inside /app/tmp) to writable as well as the cache and temp folder to writable and it is still giving the same errors. I don't know on how to CHMOD via the command prompt. So, i'm still researching on that.

Comment: I mean `/app/tmp`. It could be that your paths are messed up, but I'm not sure I understand how you've set up your Cake install. Have you followed the directives here: http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/914/Production?

Comment: Ok. No I didn't follow book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/914/Production. I will go through it and get back here. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: ok mensch, I read up your link and followed the instructions. I removed what i had uploaded earlier and ftped all files all over again. But now I'm still getting Fatal error: Can't find application core file. Please create /home/aquinto1/public_html/merryflowers.com/config/core.php, and make sure it is readable by PHP. in /home/aquinto1/cake/libs/configure.php on line 401. I've already moved the entire config from app to webroot.

Comment: I see an Internal Server Error when I visit the root domain. Have you set the correct path to the Cake core in `webroot/index.php` (shouldn't be necessary in this setup, but you never know). This problem might merit its own question though.