# cakephp: warning 512 /tmp/cache/ not writable on shared host justhost

Tags: cakephp, warnings, shared, host

When I go to www.merryflowers.com/webroot/ i'm getting the following warnings. Based on the guidance i got from my previous post (cakephp: configuring cakephp on shared host justhost), I right clicked on the app/tmp/ (on the remote server) and all the folders within that and set the permission to be writable (ie. 777). But I'm still getting the same warnings.

Since i'm using windows 7 (chmod doesn't work), I also tried CACLS on the command prompt for tmp folder. Since i'm not familiar with CACLS, i don't know the exact command to make tmp writable to all. Can someone please help me out. Thank you.

```
 Warning (512): /home/aquinto1/public_html/merryflowers.com/tmp/cache/ is not writable [CORE/cake/libs/cache/file.php, line 278].php, line 429
Warning (512): /models/ is not writable [CORE/cake/libs/cache/file.php, line 278]
Warning (512): /persistent/ is not writable [CORE/cake/libs/cache/file.php, line 278]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your site hosted locally on your Windows machine, like through XAMPP or WAMP, etc? Those are *nix paths, not Windows paths.

Did you FTP to your sites - like, with an FTP client - and change the permissions? Doing this through FTP clients isn't always 100% reliable. It looks like you changed the perms on /tmp, but they didn't cascade to /tmp/cache, etc. like you thought. Try setting them all one by one.

According to your other post - [cakephp: configuring cakephp on shared host justhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906214/cakephp-configuring-cakephp-on-shared-host-justhost) - your site is set up with remote hosting. I looked at their service briefly, from the looks of them, you can probably remote (aka, "shell" or "ssh") into your server and get access to the command line. A lot of webhosts provide this these days, although you may have to specifically request they enable it for you.

On a Windows machine, you can use PuTTY to shell into your remote server: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/

HTH. :)

Comment: no, it is not hosted locally on WAMP coz' cakephp doesn't work well with WAMP. I FTPed my site through dreamweaver to the remote server. And as u said changed the permissions on /tmp/cache directly on the remote server. I'm also not sure on which temp i'm supposed to change permissions on. /tmp/ or /app/tmp/? When u say I can shell into the remote server's command line, ru talking abt using Unix or Linux commands? based on my readings sometime back, a lot of these web hosts use Linux and not Windows. As per your suggestion, i will request justhost to enable me to access their command line.

Comment: On nix, / means "the root." So "/app" it means "the root of your application", not the root of the server. /tmp is the server's tmp directory; /app/tmp is the tmp folder in your app folder. Yes, shelling in means opening an SSH connection in PuTTY to your web server (almost exactly like what FileZilla does when you FTP in.) It's a direct connection to your remote server, so whatever (*nix) commands you run in it run directly and immediately on your server, not your Windows machine. But lot of Cake's magic is the "cake console," which you also run on the command line (same SSH remote connect.)